# Репутация за старые вопросы/ответы

Tags: обсуждение

Вопрос в целом относится "давним" участникам сайта :)

Сколько примерно репутации вам приходит за ваши "старые" вопросы/ответы, к примеру в течении месяца?

Просто стало интересно, становится ли всё легче и лечге зарабатывать много репутации на сайте, тем кто здесь "давно" или как и раньше в основном получаете репутацию за новые воспросы/ответы?

Comment: Вы можете открыть профиль любого участника и сами посмотреть как прирастает его репутация

Comment: Ориентировочно - меньше 100 на 1000 ответов.

Comment: Вот например участник с 50к+ репутации, под 1,5к ответов за прошлый месяц заработал около 80 репутации, не давая вопросов и ответов: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/23044/jfs?tab=reputation Примерно то же получается и на моей репутации, но сложнее очистить лишнее.

Comment: @insolor Спасибо за данные!

Comment: За прошлый месяц прилетело 40 репутации (600+ ответов). Это всего лишь 0.2% от общего количества. Если легче и становится, то только морально

Comment: @nomnoms12 Понятно :) Просто я когда гуглю что-то, то очень часто попадаю на вопросы, которым по 6-10 лет, и если они полезны то ставлю плюсик. А ещё в английском SO появилась возможность, сортировать ответы в порядке убывания тренда. Это значит за посленее время какой-то из ответов получал много голосов и потому он попадает в тренды. Это я так понял для того чтобы современные ответы были выше старых не обновлённых. И стало интересно как много старые вопросы/ответы приносят репутации